# How to vertically center an image containing horizontal centered text within a header block using CSS?

Tags: html, css

With Moodle 3.5 html block, I'm trying to create a header bar that will sit at the top of the page. The page heading needs to be in the middle whilst a back arrow image needs to be placed on the left hand side.

This is the code that I'm using, however the arrow is not centrally placed:

```html
<div style="text-align: center; background-color: #1e2d41; height: auto; color: #ffffff; font-size: 20px; padding: 15px; width: auto;">

  <span style="float:left;">
    <a href="https://yopa.clcmoodle.org/course/view.php?id=160"><img src="https://yopa.clcmoodle.org/draftfile.php/4156/user/draft/759697841/Backward%20White.png" alt="" width="40" height="40" role="presentation" class="img-responsive atto_image_button_text-top"></a>
  </span>

  <strong>
    Communication &amp; Social Skills
  </strong>
</div>
```

Image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

just found this article : https://teamtreehouse.com/community/text-align-center-margin-auto-which-one-is-better

From what I understand, if you try to center things apart from text you should use margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto

Since I am high afraid of CSS I tend to use both things in my div :

```
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
```

All the best,
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

I would use `display:flex` and also a stylesheet rather than inline styles (it is a lot easier to maintain and will cut down on your file size)

```css
.container {
   display:flex;           /* change display type to flex */
   flex-direction:row;     /* align child elements in a row */
   align-items:center;     /* vertical centering */
   justify-content:center; /* horizontal centering */
   
   background-color: #1e2d41;
   color: #ffffff; 
   font-size: 20px; 
   padding: 15px;
}

.container > span {
    display:inline-block;   /* make this span inline-block so it can have a width */
    width:40px;              /* make it as wide as the image */
    margin-right:1em;       /* optional spacing */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <span>
    <a href="https://via.placeholder.com/40x40" alt="" width="40" height="40" role="presentation" class="img-responsive atto_image_button_text-top"></a>
  </span>

  <strong>
    Communication &amp; Social Skills
  </strong>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, note that vertical-align is only applicable to table cells and inline-level elements.
There are couple of ways to set vertical alignments. However, I'll show you two methods which is my favorites:

**1. Using transform**

```css
.child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div style="position:relative; width:50px; height:100px;">
    <div style="position: relative;height: 56px;background-color: green;">
        <div class="child" style="background-color: red;color-:white">XYZ</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**2.Using Flexbox**

```css
.parent{
background-color:pink;
width:300px;
height:200px;
  display: -webkit-box;
   display: -ms-flexbox;
   display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">text</div>
</div>
```

To your parent element give **display:flex** and **align-items:center**. For more details about flex please refer https://cssreference.io/flexbox/

For auto prefixes, I would strongly recommend you to do so, using a tool such as [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) and [pleeease.io](http://pleeease.io/play/)

---

You can achieve by **display:table** to your parent element then **display:table-cell** and **vertical-align:middle** to your child element. For that check this [article](https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/)